# How to use drupal modules Properly

Tags: drupal

Recently my website redesigned and after redesigning it is on Drupal before it was on WordPress and have i good command over the wordpress but now i am facing the problem with Drupal  Modules .so can anybody tell me how to use Drupal Modules Properly.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a custom installation profile you should place all modules under /prodofile/your_profile/moduels.

If you don't using a custom installation profile, the most common place to put the modules in is /sites/all/modules

How to use them:

1. Download the module from drupal.org
2. Put it in the module folder (see above)
3. Go to /admin/modules and enable the module.